# If $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=I$, then $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)f(a-x)dx=\dots$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution, symmetry

A well known result of definite integrals is:

$$\int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x)dx$$

It is very easy to verify this result by substituting $x=a-y \implies dx=-dy$.

When $x=0, y=a$, and when $x=a, y=0$. Substituing this in $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx$, we get $\int_{a}^{0}f(a-y)(-dy)$. The minus sign in the integrand can be used to reverse the limits. Also we can use $x$ instead of $y$.

---

My question is:

If we know that the value of $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=I$, is there a formula to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)f(a-x)dx$$ in terms of $I$?

---

I tried to use the above result, but could not conclude anything.

---

Take this as an example;

We know that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$, is it possible to evaluate (using a formula in terms of $(\pi/4)$)

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(1-x)^2}dx$$

in terms of $\frac{\pi}{4}$, without using partial fractions decomposition?

Comment: Answer to your question is NO.

Comment: Downvoters, kindly give your reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Any proof of that (NO)?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari you seem a competent enough mathematician to find examples of $f$ with $\int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt=1$ and with $\int_{0}^{1} f(t)f(1-t)dt=1$, or $=0$ or whatever.

Comment: Construct two examples to show that $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx=I$ in both cases but $$\int_{0}^{a}f(x)f(a-x)dx$$ has different values .

Comment: Just try some examples.  For instance, if $f(x) = 2x-1$, then $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$ but $\int_0^1 f(x)f(1-x) \, dx \neq 0$

Comment: Most likely there will be some inequality cf. [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2) that may bound what you will get as $\int_0^a f(x)f(a-x)\,dx$, but within those bounds you can probably get any value for a suitably crafted function $f$.

Comment: @kaviRamaMurthy $I$ is the same in both cases, I know. Still no reason to say NO. There is a possibility that $\int_{0}^{a}f(x)f(a-x)dx$ can be expressed in terms of $I$ and a relation with $f$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari It sounds like there is no argument that can be given to you that will convince you that the answer is NO. If you are not willing to accept the answer, then why ask the question? If such a formula did exist, then you could find it if you searched the literature. Even just using Google should suffice.

Comment: Rather than asking whether it's true or not (which as pointed out is not), then perhaps rephrase the question to: what set (or space) of functions satisfies the relation. This would be more insightful.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to consider only the case when $f:[-R,R]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is real-analytic on $(-R,R),$ and we let $a\in(0,R),$ for simplicity. In that case, there exists some $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,\;x\in(-R.R).$$ Under that consideration, $$f(a-x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(a-x)^n$$ and $$\int_0^af(x)f(a-x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\int_0^a(a-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ For $n=0,$ the integral $$\int_0^a(a-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$ is trivial, and is equal to $I.$ However, it is more complicated for $n\gt0.$ By Leibniz' integral rule, we have that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{a}}\int_0^a(a-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=(a-a)^nf(a)+\int_0^a\frac{\partial}{\partial{a}}(a-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=n\int_0^a(a-x)^{n-1}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ As such, one can define $$I_n(a)=\int_0^a(a-x)^nf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$$ where $$I_0(a)=I,$$ thus having that $$I_n'(a)=nI_{n-1}(a).$$ Also, notice that $$I_n(0)=0$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Hence $$I_n(a)=n\int_0^aI_{n-1}(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$ or $$I_{n+1}(a)=(n+1)\int_0^aI_n(s)\,\mathrm{d}s,$$ which is the perfect recursion to solve for $I_n(a)$ in terms of $I_0(a)=I.$ This implies that $$I_{n+2}(a)=(n+2)(n+1)\int_0^a\int_0^tI_n(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t.$$ If we adopt the convention of defining a linear operator $J$ defined by $J[g]=\int_0^ag(x)\,\mathrm{d}x,$ then we in general have that $$I_{n+m}(a)=\frac{(n+m)!}{n!}(J^m)[I_n](a),$$ which can be proven by simply applying the principle of induction. Letting $n=0,$ it would result in $$I_m(a)=m!(J^m)[I_0](a).$$ Thankfully, we have a formula for repeated integration by Cauchy: $$(J^m)[g]=\frac1{(m-1)!}\int_0^a(a-x)^{m-1}g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Therefore, $$I_n(a)=n\int_0^a(a-x)^{n-1}I_0(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ Therefore, $$\int_0^af(x)f(a-x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nI_n(a)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_n\int_0^a(a-x)^{n-1}I_0(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$ This is by no means a closed-form formula, though, as this involves an abstract integral within an infinite series.